# .NET MVC: How to define ntext field in Code-First for SQL CE?

Tags: code-first, sql-server-ce, ntext

I have the following model:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(70)]
    [Required]
    public string BlogTitle { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="ntext")]
    public string BlogContent { get; set; }
}
```

I have manually set the field `BlogContent` to be of `ntext` type (16 bytes) in the `SQL CE4` database.

However, every time I try to insert text longer than 4000 characters, it gives the following error:

> Validation failed for one or more
>   entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors'
>   property for more details

I have tried setting the annotation for `[Column(TypeName="ntext")]`, but this makes no difference. When I loop trough the `EntityValidationErrors` collection, the problem is caused by `BlogContent` and the error says:

> String cannot be longer than 4000 characters

How can I define my model to have an `ntext` field for `BlogContent`?

It seems that any data annotations are ignored; it is assuming that a string with no `MaxLength` is limited to 4000 characters by default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have solved it, you need to use:

```
[Column(TypeName="ntext")]
[MaxLength]
public string BlogContent { get; set; }
```

See details here:
http://www.cloudonedesign.com/Blog/Post/how-to-define-ntext-fields-using-code-first-in-net-30

> In order to create an `ntext` column in the database, and allow model validation
>   to actually know that the string length can be more than 4,000 characters, we
>   have to use these two items:
>
> `[Column(TypeName="ntext")]`: This will tell Code-First to generate an
>   ntext field in the database.
>
> `[MaxLength]`: By using the default
>   constructor, it will take the maximum length of the database field,
>   instead of guessing the maximum length for a string, which is 4,000. If this is
>   missing or you explicitly set the maximum length such as `[MaxLength(8000)]`, model validation will
>   raise errors saying "String maximum length is 4,000 characters".